# How to specify range (PlotRange) for BodePlot function?

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I am using the BodePlot function to plot magnitude and phase of the function below:

```
BodePlot[(1 + s/10^6)/((1 + s/10^2)*(1 + s/10^12)), PlotRange -> All]
```

I got the plots as below. However, I want to see the magnitude and phase of that function for frequencies larger than 10^13 Hz (the red region as in the picture).

Could you tell me how to do that? I tried to modify the PlotRange function as below but it doesn't work.

```
BodePlot[(1 + s/10^6)/((1 + s/10^2)*(1 + s/10^12)), PlotRange -> {{0.1, 10^15}, {-100, 0}}]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BodePlot[(1 + s/10^6)/((1 + s/10^2) (1 + s/10^12)), {10, 10^20}]
```

The second argument should be the frequency range (horizontal axis).  If you use `PlotRange`, that affects the **vertical** axis, which is not what you want.  Refer to the documentation:

```
?BodePlot
```

---

In response to your follow-up request, try these options:

```
BodePlot[(1 + s/10^6)/((1 + s/10^2) (1 + s/10^12)), {.1, 10^20},
     PlotRange -> {{-150, 50}, {-180, 90}}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
     AxesOrigin -> {{0, 0.1}, {0, 0.1}}]
```

The thing to understand about the default output of `BodePlot` is that it plots **two** graphs, and the vertical scale on each is different; therefore, when supplying plotting options, they must be given as a list.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. However, is there a way to make PlotRange works? I tried to make the vertical axis wider range than what the function value but why does it also not work?